# What is "cognitoUser.getAttributeVerificationCode"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm convinced that Amazon goes out of its way to make understanding their platform as difficult as is possible.

I've read over the documentation regarding "cognitoUser.getAttributeVerificationCode" at Amazon only to have it make me even more confused!

> Verify an Attribute
>   The following example verifies user attributes for an authenticated user.

```
cognitoUser.getAttributeVerificationCode('email', {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
        console.log('call result: ' + result);
    },
    onFailure: function(err) {
        alert(err);
    },
    inputVerificationCode: function() {
        var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code: ' ,'');
        cognitoUser.verifyAttribute('email', verificationCode, this);
    }
});
```

Can anyone help me understand what this is (cognitoUser.getAttributeVerificationCode) and/or how I would use it? I don't understand why I would verify an email attribute w/a verification code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verification code is sent to the users email. The user has to properly receive that email to retrieve the code and enter it in a UI so that the email is set to verified in Cognito. That user can then reset their password using that email.

What if the user had entered an incorrect email? Or their email system didn't allow them to receive the code sent by AWS?

By sending out a verification code, and having the user send it back, Cognito verifies that the email was entered correctly and belongs to that user. This can seem like a pain but is standard on many web platforms now days...The same process is needed with phone numbers for users in your Cognito user pool.

Comment: If my answers have been helpful to you, please accept them, or let me know if you have further questions :)

Comment: What if we are running test suites and want to run a test for signing up and then confirming. Will this method help us in any way to retrieve the verification code sent? Or is there any other way?

Comment: @AzherAleem I know it's been a year since you asked that, but no, if you are trying to confirm the user, that is "automatically" done in your UserPool. For example, you can use a CustomEmailSender function in your UserPool, when a user signs up, this will be called with a `CustomEmailSender_SignUp` triggerSource, this will include a code that is used to confirm the user. The function being asked about is used to verify your email or phone number. User confirmation is different from attribute verification.